# What's Include() method's job in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I have two entities Permission and Access

**Access.cs**

```
public class Access
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Permission> PermissionList { get; set; }
}
```

**Permission.cs**

```
public class Permission
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int ParentId { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public bool HasChildren { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public List<Permission> ChildPermissions { get; set; }
}
```

I also have GenericRepository class to filter records in my database.

**GenericRepository.cs**

```
 public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
            Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
            Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
            string includeProperties = "", bool tracking = true)
        {
            IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;


            if (filter != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(filter);
            }

            foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
                (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            {
                query = query.Include(includeProperty);
            }
        /*...*/
        }
```

I call this method in my Access Service class

**AccessService.cs**

```
GenericRepository<Access> accessRepo = new GenericRepository<Access>();
List<Access> accessList = accessRepo.Get(d => d.Name == accessName, null, "PermissionList").OrderBy(d => d.Id).ToList();
```

This code filters records type of "Access" and then uses Include() method with "PermissionList" parameter in the Generic Repository. What's Include("PermissionList") method's job?
What does it do? PermissionList is a property of Access and has elements type of Permission. But I couldn't totaly get what's its aim.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is for eagerly loading related entities.

See [Entity Framework Loading Related Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx).

When not using Include(), this query:

```
using (var context = new YourContext())
{
    var access = context.Access.Single(a => a.ID == 42);    
}
```

Would return an `Access` instance with an empty `PermissionList` property. Depending on how your context is configured, this collection would remain empty (no lazy loading) or would be lazy-loaded as soon as you access it (`foreach (var permission in access.PermissionList) { ... }`).

Now with `Include()`:

```
using (var context = new YourContext())
{
    var access = context.Access.Include(a => a.PermissionList)
                               .Single(a => a.ID == 42);    
}
```

The query will be written as a join, loading all related permissions for you.

The `Include()` extension method also has a string overload, which your repository code is invoking:

```
query = query.Include(includeProperty);
```

This causes in your case `"PermissionList"` to be eagerly loaded, and it seems to support multiple `Include()`s using a comma-separated list (e.g. `"PermissionList,PermissionList.ChildPermissions"`).